# SignalR Hub's Groups dont work with long polling

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a Web App(.NET 4.0 ASP.NET MVC3) which uses SignalR(1.0.0 alpha 2) with Hubs and Persistent Connections.

With the Hubs I use groups to send push notifications to some clients.

The problem is that when the server is accessed remotely it defaults to long pooling and only the persistent connections work. With hubs the event happens on the server but my callback is not called at the client. It works locally, though it uses SSE.

What I found is that the combination of Grouping the clients and the long pooling transport is causing the problem. I will try to debug SignalR as long as I get VS2012.

To prove this I just got this [chat example](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs) modified so a hard-coded group was used and long pooling was forced - it does not work, neither on my machine (IISExpress) nor on a server (IIS 7.5). The chat works as long as you use a different transport OR do

```
context.Clients.All.addMessage(message);
```

instead of

```
context.Clients.Group(groupName).addMessage(message);
```

[Here](http://tranzit.dir.bg/load.php?id=Q4r6N8xPMXjiMlr21440095) is a sample project.

Is that a bug in SignalR or I'm missing something?

Any ideas why on my deployment server SignalR would fall back to long polling on port 80 but use SSE if my site is configured on a different port?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable Auto-Rejoining groups.

Stick this in your startup code:

GlobalHost.HubPipeline.EnableAutoRejoiningGroups();

Comment: Thank you, John ! That + updating SignalR to rc1 solved the problem(it didn't work with the alpha version). Where can I get more info about this nothing is mentioned in signalR's wiki, the documentation is very poor... what about my second question with the port, any ideas?

Comment: I just happened to stumble across the same answer a few days ago.

Ever since the change to ASP.Net SignalR, the documentation is patchy, given how many examples etc already existed out there.

Comment: In SignalR 1.0 EnableAutoRejoiningGroups has been removed from HubPipeline as it is now turned on by default. https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md