# SignalR 1.0.1 "group messages" not working on production server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I've created a Chat application(.NET MVC4) in SignalR that works great on my development machine. But when I upload it to our production server, my client is not receiving any calls to the "groups".

When I do:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
context.Clients.All.addOnline(profielidVan);
```

It works great! But when I do:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
context.Clients.Group(profielidNaar).addOnline(profielidVan);
```

My client is not receiving any calls.

To get a connection into the correct group, I call a function on the Hub called Join() at the start of every SignalR connection:

```
$(function () {

    var chat = $.connection.Chat;

    chat.client.addOnline = function (profielid) {
        if ($("#profielidNaar").val() == profielid) {
            var now = new Date()
            $("#onlinetime").val(now);
            $('#typtbericht').html('Online');
        }
    };

    // ... code to the other jQuery functions called by SignalR ...

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

         chat.server.join();

         // ... code to the page jQuery functions (like $(window).resize) ...

    }
}
```

And the serverside code:

```
[HubName("Chat")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public Task Join()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Profiel_DataHelper profiel = new Profiel_DataHelper(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, profiel.ProfielID.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    ...
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Well the show code would imply that the user is not authenticated, what form of authentication is the site using?

Comment: I'm using standard memberships provider authentication. But the user is authenticated, that's not te problem, the page won't show if the user is not authenticated. And otherwise the problem would also show on my development machine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934676/signalr-hubs-groups-dont-work-with-long-polling <<< This problem is EXACTLY the same as mine, but his solution is not available anymore in SignalR v1.0.1, because it has been applied by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, the solution to this problem was because of the following:

1. I used the HubName attribute on my Hub, this is a bug of SignalR.
2. I used the nickname of the membership provider to lookup the profile. But because the nickname "Willem" is registrated on multiple domains it returned the wrong ProfileID.

So if your having the same problem as mine, try adding your client to a hardcoded group (like "test") If it works, then you'll know the problem lies with your own code.

Thanks David Fowler!